# custom d3 scale for values and distance

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got to display a chart of a couple of million values in relation with distance ( expressed in meters ), I'm pretty new to the d3 philosophy so I'm finding a hard time getting my head around this.

The data that I've got to put on screen, are stored in a file that is quite hard to use, this is the format:

```
    CLK 2
    -0.000051
    -0.000084
    ..
    ..
    -0.000084
    -0.000116

    CLK 3
    -0.000084
    -0.000084
    -0.000051
    ..
    -0.000149
    -0.000051

    CLK 4
    -0.000051
    -0.000116
    ..
    -0.000042
    -0.000122
```

so basically, the int value aside of every "CLK" is the number of the meter, and all the values between any "CLK" and "CLK" are to be evenly distributed in the chart.
To make myself clear, this is an (ugly) example of the type of visualization I'd like to achieve:

[image: The result I'd like to achieve]

Comment: [`d3.scale.linear()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear)? It sounds like you should be able to apply one of the D3 scales without any problems.

Comment: could u pls provide some code to explain it? Thx!

Comment: The documentation I've linked to has an example further down.

Comment: Yes, I had already read the doc b4 writing this post, but unfortunately the code in the example didn't give me enought clues to get on the right path. thx anyway

Comment: You put the range of input values in `.domain()` and the range of output values in `.range()`.

Comment: yeah, I pretty much ( already ) got it, this implies that I've to parse the original data file in another ( more compatible ) format, right?

Comment: You need to be able to access the values for a given series.